# Check if Hard Disk uses RAID

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement wherein I need to check if the hard disk isn't RAID before turning on a feature that encrypts the hard disk. Is there a built-in class in C# that would let me find this? I looked at the [MSDN-DriveInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class and it does not seem to have that information.

Comment: did you look at WMI?

Comment: You can't reliably do this. Even if you find out a way to detect Microsoft's implementation of RAID, you cannot detect that they have a hardware RAID controller with RAID enabled, unless you check for every possible hardware manufacturer and interrogate the card (probably with unmanaged code for each and every card). This is because hardware raid cards simply present the whole drive as a single device to windows.

Comment: Why can't you turn on encryption on a RAID disk?  They should work just fine together.

Comment: @DStanley: Unfortunately, what I am looking for should work under the umbrella of a proprietry software of my company which is designed not to work with RAID and I have no control over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can check if a hard drive is RAID, I am pretty sure you can't because the hard drive just looks like one physical drive, but I would look into Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI), the .NET libraries are System.Management and System.Management.Instrumentation, here is an article that demos usage:

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/getting-hard-disk-information-with-wmi-and-visual-studio-2012.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WMI, you can test BusType of [MSFT_Disk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830493.aspx). I am not sure how reliable it is though.